# How can I get Ant to "chomp" newlines at the end of files?

Tags: ant, apache-stringutils

I'm using the Ant [LoadFile](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadfile.html) task to read the version from a file in the repository root.

```
<loadfile property="build.version" srcFile="VERSION"/>
```

The version file ends with a newline due to the tooling used to create and edit it. Ant is reading and using that newline as part of the property value. That's jamming me up when I use the value as a replacement for a file or output.

```
@build.version@ -> 99.0.0.0^M
```

Is there some way to strip that out of the property after loading or as part of the loadfile task?

---

I'm talking about this kind of [Chomp](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#chomp(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

---

The `VERSION` file literally contains only the version number and a newline (line numbers are mine for illustration).

```
1. 99.0.0.0
2.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a `filterchain` to remove such line breaks:

```
<loadfile property="build.version" srcFile="VERSION">
    <filterchain>
        <striplinebreaks/>
    </filterchain>
</loadfile>
```

See https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#striplinebreaks.

Comment: `striplinebreaks` works well for single-line inputs, in general a combination of `trim` and `fixcrlf` may be more appropriate.

Comment: @StefanBodewig, I'd love to see an example of that... I'm not so familiar, are those filterchain options?

Comment: Oh, I just realized I was talking about the more general case of reading a property file with multiple lines rather than a single file read into a property at once.  For your case @manouti's answer is the best solution.  For an example of the other filterreaders see https://gist.github.com/bodewig/d416666c701c313616c1